# unable to create multiple content folders in marketing cloud using REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I am trying to create content folders using REST API using post method(POST /asset/v1/content/categories).I have used the below request body am i am successful when i am trying to insert one folder per request.

```
Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
POST /asset/v1/content/categories
Content-Type: application/json Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
{ "Name" : "My Pictures", "ParentId" : 99 }
```

However I am trying to insert multiple folders in a single request by sending the data in an array like the below request and i am unsuccessful:

```
Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
POST /asset/v1/content/categories
Content-Type: application/json Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
[
{ "Name" : "My Pictures", "ParentId" : 99 }
{ "Name" : "My Pictures1", "ParentId" : 99 }
]
```

I tried multiple ways but I keep failing. Has anyone come across this scenario.

Regards,
Rumi.

Comment: I don't know if multiple categories are supported.  But, I see a syntax error in your json.  Your array elements should be separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

From everything I have seen, this endpoint can only be used to create a single category/folder per call.

Your above call body was missing a comma after the first object - but even adding that it still failed.  I sincerely think this will only do one at a time.

> Creates a category (folder) in Content Builder.

[More details here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createCategory.htm)